# What is the gold charm taken from the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, millennium-falcon, the-last-jedi

During the *The Last Jedi* Luke is shown boarding the Millennium Falcon and while he is in the cockpit he takes a golden charm (looks like dice tethered on a chain). I have never seen them before, but it seems they are recognizable enough to not be explained in the new film...

**What exactly is this charm?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**These are ["Han Solo's dice"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo%27s_dice).**

It seem no offical name has been given to the charm, but they were

> ...Used to play the sabacc variant known as "Corellian Spike." During a game of Spike against Lando Calrissian, Solo won his opponent's YT-1300 light freighter, the Millennium Falcon, thanks to those dice. Solo kept the gaming devices and hung them in the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon as a lucky charm.

[image]
<sub><sup>Image from [The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

They can be seen all the way back in *A New Hope* if look closely. However it seems they disappear for remainder of the original trilogy.

[image]

Comment: Are the Han Solo adventure books canon? Those claim that Han won the Falcon as part of a massive sabacc tournament, and Calrissian added "any ship on my lot" as part of a wager, not remembering the Falcon was on the lot.

Comment: @JohnP That seems to be the case. My quote comes from the Canon section of the entry for the dice on the wikia.

Comment: @Skooba - That's what I thought. The books are great Solo backstory, but I have no idea what is and is not canon in the SW universe anymore. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnP The information  from The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary, so while the Han Solo books are not canon it appears they took *some* information from legends soruces and made it canon.

Comment: @DangerZone They disappeared because they were never really there. They were brought by Luke, and given to Leia. SPOILER ALERT! But we find out that Luke wasn't really there, so the charm must have been an illusion as well.

Comment: Just because it may be of interest to you, they're Sabacc dice.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the image from the FA: Visual Dictionary that canonically confirms their identity and usage.

Comment: Should also be noted that the Visual Dictionary illustration shows dice with pips on them, whereas the dice seen in *Last Jedi* have different symbols, possibly numerals in Aurebesh, the writing system for Galactic Basic.